# PLS-00049: bad bind variable ' while creating procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11gr2

Hi I'm trying to create a procedure for which the code is given below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE profit_calcs(profit OUT NUMBER,
                              em     IN NUMBER,
                              eq     IN NUMBER,
                              p      IN NUMBER,
                              u      IN NUMBER,
                              income IN NUMBER,
                              ex     IN NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO em FROM a_em;
  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO eq FROM a_eq;
  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO p FROM a_p;
  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO u FROM a_u;
  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO income FROM sales;
  ex     := :em + :eq + :p + :u;
  profit := :income - :ex;
END;
/
```

whenever I'm trying to create it I'm getting the following error:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
10/7      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'EM'
10/13     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'EQ'
10/18     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'P'
10/22     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'U'
11/11     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'INCOME'
11/21     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'EX'
```

It will be very helpful if someone helps me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, you need to define those variables at the declaration section just after the keyword `AS`, before `BEGIN` such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE profit_calcs(profit OUT NUMBER,
                                         ex     OUT NUMBER) AS
  em     INT;
  eq     INT;
  p      INT;
  u      INT;
  income INT;                             
BEGIN
```

**or** convert them to `OUT` type parameters for this stored procedure such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE profit_calcs(profit OUT NUMBER,
                                         em     OUT NUMBER,
                                         eq     OUT NUMBER,
                                         p      OUT NUMBER,
                                         u      OUT NUMBER,
                                         income OUT NUMBER,
                                         ex     OUT NUMBER) AS                           
BEGIN
```

where

- don't forget to remove colons prefixing those variables such as
  `:em`,`:eq` should be `em`,`eq` respectively
- `REPLACE` option for `CREATE PROCEDURE` command shouldn't be omitted
  considering the upcoming compilations

Comment: LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
`0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/1       PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted`

Comment: you have 7 variables those shouldn't be repeated @s5190 . Please recheck out the answer. Btw. Did you get rid of the colons prefixing some of the variables.

Comment: You can check [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8684c653df98ca091b2a092691baca7d) out also. Eg. Just prefer one the two methods.

Comment: thank you so much the problem is solved !